# What does mean by semantic?

Tags: semantic-web, semantics

I am searching the term 'Semantic Query Optimization'. But can't find any specific answer. Can you tell me what actually **Semantic** means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as another way of saying something, usually in a way that's easier to understand.

For example: HTML5 includes semantic tags.

The semantic version of `<div id="header"></div>` is simply `<header></header>` It's just another way of stating the same thing.

There is a front-end framework known as [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/). In this framework, you can specify a four column row like this `<div class="four wide column"></div>` If you're familiar with the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) framework, you'd know the equivalent to be `<div class="col-4"></div>`.

In conclusion, they both do the same thing, but they're stated differently.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and should not have been accepted. The semantics the question refers to correspond to the application of formal knowledge representation. Concepts, roles, and individuals are defined in ontologies to cover knowledge domains; these are described with very rich semantics that can define virtually any real-world object or action, and these semantics are lightyears away from the semantics of HTML markup elements, e.g., using a section instead of a p element does not describe the semantics (meaning) of the content better, just refers to the type of the content. Now see RDF.

Answer (score 1):

Semantics means meaning (the term is borrowed from linguistics). On the Semantic Web, the meaning of things is expressed as structured data, such as in the form of RDF triples—think of the meaning of concepts defined in OWL ontologies. Therefore, semantic query means querying structured data, most often with SPARQL. Semantic query optimization is about optimizing such queries.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic usually refers to the term of a type of data formatted into triples like this:

(subject, predicate, object)

In the world of the [Semantic Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web) (standard [here](https://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb/)) that kind of queries means searches over structures following the triple pattern using specific languages like [SPARQL](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/).

Hope this helps.